# how to find indexes where value changes

Tags: javascript, typescript

hello I have an array of strings with values in a list, I mean, the only valid values are "a", "b", "c"

In general with it's "a" it's "a" during some time, so, what I want to know is the indexes they changed.

For example:

```
const myList = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b"]
const result = //returns [6,10]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. You just need to use a loop and check if the current item is different than the previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just loop through elements and compare the current element with the previous one.

```js
const myList = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b"]
const result = []; 

myList.map((el, index) => {
  return myList[index-1] !== el && index > 0 && result.push(index)
})

console.log(result)
```